# C# default value in text box to be max value from field in SQL database and increment

Tags: c#, sql

I have an add new row button that I want to trigger a default value in one of the text boxes, I want the default value to be the MAX value that is currently in the tab + 1.

So if the MAX value in the table is 7, when the add new row button is pressed it inserts 8 into the text box.

I have added

```
employeeIDTextBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.newEmployeedefault;
```

To my button and created `newEmployeedefault` in `Settings.settings`. However I am unsure of what value to use in there.

I have tried `SELECT MAX(EmployeeID)+1 FROM Employees` but it literally displays this as is in the text box.

Or do i need to do this in the code and not in the Settings.settings?

Comment: Only use the Visual Studio tags if your question is *about* Visual Studio, not for general coding questions.

Comment: Are you trying to do a unique I'd...if so use a sequence or auto Inc column in the DB...not max plus 1

Comment: @Ctznkane525, tried that but auto increment doesnt pull through to windows forms when i asked]

Comment: You don't need an Id until after the insert...your approach probably should be revisited if it uses max plus 1

Comment: @Matt The point is you don't need, and can't even know the ID before inserting to the DB, DB may be a cluster with sparse ID's, or may be more than one user can be working on the same DB and may be inserting at the same time, etc. This may be for a single user program, but never, ever, create your ID's manually unless you use GUID's, a collission may occur. Also, your user doesn't needs at all the ID field until it has been inserted, if you want some UI-sugar add a row with the cardinal position, just that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the button click i added the following code between the `employeesBindingSource.AddNew();` line.

```
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
        int b = a + 1;
        employeesBindingSource.AddNew();
        employeeIDTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
```

Full Add New button code:

```
    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
        int b = a + 1;
        employeesBindingSource.AddNew();
        employeeIDTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
    }
```